# Computing Probabilities with Several Normally Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I encountered the following problem.

$X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent normally distributed random variables with expected values $2$, $1$, and $0$, respectively. They all have the same variance $2$. Compute $P(4X - 3Y > 5Z )$.

I don't really know how to approach this problem. I tried defining a new variable as $U = 4X - 3Y$, which would then have and expected value of $5$ and a variance of $14$, but then I don't know how to deal with this new variable U, given that we have still $5Z$ on the other side of the inequality. I never get to the correct solution of $0.6915$. Also, $Z$ is not yet standardized either, since its variance is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the joint density, you could define the new variable $V:= 4X-3Y-5Z$ which is a normal random variable with expected value $5$ and variance $32+18+50=100$ (the variances add even if the random variables are subtracted).  Then you just need $P(4X-3Y > 5Z) = P(V > 0)$, and $P(V>0)$ can be computed by standardizing $V$.

Comment: very nice! this should be *the* answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

You need the "[joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution)" $f(x,y,z)$ and
$$
P(4X-3Y>5Z)=\iiint_{A}f(x,y,z)dxdydz
$$
where $A=\{(x,y,z):4x-3y>5z\}$

But since $X,Y,Z$ are independent, the joint density is given by $f(x,y,z)=h(x)g(y)l(z)$, where $h,g,l$ are the density functions for $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.

---

The approach above is a general one. But your problem has special properties.

[@user6247850's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3990686/872872) is very nice and here is a remark about it.

In general, any linear combination of *independent* normal-distributed random variables is of normal distribution.

In particular, if $X_i\sim N(\nu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ are independent, then
$$
\sum a_iX_i\sim N(\sum a_i\mu_i,\sqrt{\sum a_i^2\sigma_i^2})
$$

See for instance this set of lecture notes: [http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/introstatistics/introstats_normal_linear_combinations.pdf](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Enchristo/introstatistics/introstats_normal_linear_combinations.pdf)

So once you know the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ for the random variable $4X-3Y-5Z$, you get
$$
P(4X-3Y-5Z>0)=1-P(\frac{4X-3Y-5Z-\mu}{\sigma}\le -\mu)=1-\Phi(-\mu)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF for the standard normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint! I did some research and found that the product of normally distributed random variables is a Chi-square distribution. We did not have that in class, but it interests me regardless. I assume I would have to consult a special Chi-square table to solve this?

Comment: @Luca: You are welcome. No, you don't need the Chi-square distribution. Do you know how to find the density functions $h,g,l$ in my answer?

Comment: Are the densities not by definition normal distributions? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Luca: yes, they are. Then all you need is just calculating the triple integral. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes I know how to do that, but it can get quite complex with three normal distributions...

Comment: @Luca: notes added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped!

Comment: @Luca: you are welcome!